# Cannot updated item Author and Editor with powershell

Tags: powershell, list-item, update

I've copied some files from one library to another with Powersehll.

Now I'm trying to update Author and Editor.
Unfortunately, the author remains the user with wich I copied the item and the editor results empty.

Here is the code I have used:

```
[SPListItem]$spfilein = $spwebin.GetListItem($urltofilein) 
   [SPListItem] $spfileout = $spwebout.GetListItem($urltofileout)

    [SPUser] $userin =  $spfilein["Author"]

    [SPFieldUserValue] $val = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($spwebin, $userin.ID, $userin.Name);


            $spfileout["Author"] =  $val;
            $spfileout["Editor"] =  $spfilein["Editor"];
            $spfileout.UpdateOverwriteVersion(); # $spfileout.Update() same result
            $spwebout.Update();
```

I've also tried:

```
        $spfileout["Author"] =  $spfilein["Author"];
        $spfileout["Editor"] =  $spfilein["Editor"];
        $spfileout.UpdateOverwriteVersion();   
        $spwebout.Update();
```

Do you know what is wrong?

**EDIT:**
Even tried the code below. Author remain empty.

```
    $spfileout["Author"] =  $spfilein["Author"];
    $spfileout["Editor"] =  $spfilein["Editor"];

    $spfileout.Properties["vti_author"] = $userin.LoginName
    $spfileout.Properties["vti_modifiedby"] = $userin.LoginName


    $spfileout.Update();
```

**EDIT2**
One problem I had was that the user on $spwebout had never acessed the site and that caused the empty author,editor.
Anyway, even so I cannot save the author afeter updating the list item author and edittor become the administrative user I am using for the update.

I've tride even impersonating as suggested by one of the answerer but no luck as author and editor become the script runner.

```
 $s = get-impersonatedsite -url:"http://myurl/mysitecollection" -user: $userAuthor.LoginName
           [SPWeb] $spwebout = $s.OpenWeb() 

          [SPListItem] $spfileout = $spwebout.GetListItem($urltomyfile)
                        $spfileout["Author"] =  $userAuthor;
            $spfileout["Editor"] =  $userAuthor;
            $spfileout.Update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using wrong `SPWeb` to create `SPFieldUserValue` in this line:

```
[SPFieldUserValue] $val = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($spwebin, $userin.ID, $userin.Name);
```

You're using `$spwebin` to create value assigned to `$spfileout`.

There should be no problems to update `Author` field. If user does not exist on target web, you need to use `SPWeb.EnsureUser()` method.

This should be enough:

```
$spfilein = $spwebin.GetListItem($urltofilein)
$spfileout = $spwebout.GetListItem($urltofileout)

$inAuthor = [Convert]::ToString($spfilein['Author'])
$inValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue $webin, $inAuthor

$outUser = $outweb.EnsureUser($inValue.User.LoginName)

$spfileout['Author'] = $outUser
$spfileout.Update()
```

This line wont work, because users may have different IDs on different webs.

```
$spfileout["Author"] =  $spfilein["Author"];
```

This line is not required, because you don't change properties of SPWeb:

```
$spwebout.Update();
```

Also specifying variable types in PowerShell looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

Created By & Modified By columns are “Person or Goup” type columns. In SharePoint all the lists has these columns by default. You can’t update the values of these columns from UI

You can do it using the below mentioned MSDN link

[Updating the “Created By” and “Modified By” Columns in SharePoint lists using POWERSHELL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tadd/2008/05/22/updating-the-created-by-and-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell/)

Comment: the link you posted propose just what I did.

Comment: Good one.. I was just helping you by giving the answer

Comment: is that link helps you as a solution?

Comment: no it did't. It's on method I'd showed in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This actually worked for me

> $modifiedby = $sourceitem["Editor"]
>
> $author = $sourceitem["Author"]
>
> $destinationitem["Author"] = $author
>
> $destinationitem["Editor"] = $modifiedby

Answer (score 0):

After setting the Author and Editor field values, do the following:

```
$spfileout.Properties["vti_author"] = $userin.LoginName
$spfileout.Properties["vti_modifiedby"] = $userin.LoginName
```

Another note: you don't need to update the `SPWeb` object at the end of your script if you are just changing `SPListItem`.

Comment: I tried SPweb.Update just to see if it could help. Anyway, I've edited the post. Even with your addition  the problems is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do impersonation with author of each item.

```
#get a spsite object using the token of a specified user, "impersonating" the object
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
cls

#use global so everything gets disposed
start-spassignment -global

function get-impersonatedsite (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $url,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $username
)
{
    try {
        $site = get-spsite $url -ea 0
        if ($site -eq $null) {
            throw "site not found: $url"
        }
        $web = $site.rootweb
        $user = $web.EnsureUser($username)
        if ($user -eq $null) {
            throw "user not found: $username"
        }
        $token = $user.usertoken
        $isite = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite($url, $token)
        return $isite
    }
    catch {
        write-host "error:" $_
    }
 }

try {
    // Pass author login name
    $s = get-impersonatedsite -url:"<<Your Site collection url>>" -user:"<<domain\user name>>"
    #do something as that user with $s
}
catch {
    write-host "error:" $_
}
finally {
    stop-spassignment -global
}
```

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you